# Why is "... how it's to be a child" incorrect?

Tags: contractions

> It is easy to forget _________ to be a child.

(A) how it`s
(B) what it is like
(C) how is it
(D) what does it feels like

The answer is **(B)**. And I know (C) and (D) have grammatical errors. However, I don't realize why (A) is faulty. Is the fault just that the contraction can't be allowed, or something?

Comment: ... And now that your question has been migrated, Welcome to ELL, too!

Comment: I know you just endured a forced migration, but you'll find many insights into this issue back at ELU at [**this link.**](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/500/192771)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*How it **is*** would be marginally acceptable here, but only marginally; and in that context *is* must be stressed, so the contraction is impossible.

Comment: _How it is_ sounds 100% acceptable to me. But you are right that a stressed _is_ can't be contracted.

Comment: I think our idiom expects "It is easy to forget _how [adj] it is_ to be a child".

Answer (score 0):

"What it is… " would be much more natural but very few listeners would mind "How it is…" which is largely why P. E. Dant is right to expect "It is easy to forget how [adj] it is to be a child"